# Merge two data frames while keeping a certain row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

***My Target***

I'd like to merge two data frames while keeping the row, `row_to_keep`

***Data Frames***

```
>>> df

                ColumnA             Stats
0               Cake                872
1               Cheese Cake         912  
2               Egg                 62
3               Raspberry Jam       091
4               Bacon               123
5               Bread               425
row_to_keep     NaN                 999

>>> df1

                ColumnB  
0               Cake  
1               Cheese Cake    
3               Raspberry Jam  
4               Bacon
```

***My Attempt***

```
new_df = df.merge(df1, left_on="ColumnA", right_on="ColumnB")

>>> new_df

                ColumnA         Stats    ColumnB
0               Cake            872      Cake
1               Cheese Cake     912      Cheese Cake
3               Raspberry Jam   091      Raspberry Jam
4               Bacon           123      Bacon
```

***Expected Output***

The merge works as expected, but I'm struggling to find an efficient way to keep the last row of `df`.

```
                ColumnA         Stats
0               Cake            872
1               Cheese Cake     912  
3               Raspberry Jam   091
4               Bacon           123
row_to_keep     NaN             999
```

Furthermore, would there be a method of such that gets this output, by using `'row_to_keep'` instead of the `row[number]`?

Comment: ...how about doing a left join of `df` to `df1` via the `merge` method?

Comment: Or You could add the row later to the `new_df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [139]: df[df.ColumnA.isin(df1.ColumnB)].append(df.loc['row_to_keep'])
Out[139]:
                   ColumnA  Stats
0                     Cake    872
1              Cheese Cake    912
3            Raspberry Jam     91
4                    Bacon    123
row_to_keep            NaN    999
```

**Old answer:**

Here is one solution:

```
In [126]: df.merge(df1, left_on="ColumnA", right_on="ColumnB").append(df.loc['row_to_keep'])
Out[126]:
                   ColumnA  Stats        ColumnB
0                     Cake    872           Cake
1              Cheese Cake    912    Cheese Cake
2            Raspberry Jam     91  Raspberry Jam
3                    Bacon    123          Bacon
row_to_keep            NaN    999            NaN
```

Explanation:

`df.loc['row_to_keep']` selects one row by index value (`'row_to_keep'`) and `DF.append(row)` - appends it to the merged DF

I must admit though, there might be less ugly solutions...

Comment: That's good enough for me! Thanks :) May I quickly ask for an explanation/clarification over `.loc` in reference to my question?

Comment: @BenF97, i've added a very short explanation to the answer. You may also want to read [about different-choices-for-indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)

Comment: Sweet ;-) Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry! One last question, I'm currently using `df.drop('ColumnB', 1)` to drop `ColumnB` since it's unnecessary once merged. Is there a method to merge  the `df`'s without the instance of `ColumnB` (As shown in my Expected Output)? (Without another line of code)

Comment: @BenF97, yes, sorry, i didn't pay enough attention at your desired DF - i just didn't notice that you don't need any information from the `df1` DF - it's used just for filtering. Please check my updated answer...